# $\bigcap _{H \ne \left\{e \right\}}H \ne \left\{e \right\}$ implies every element in $G$ has a finite order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H \le G$, if for every $H \ne \left\{e \right\}$ : $\bigcap _{H \ne \left\{e \right\}}H$ is a subgroup different from $\left\{e \right\}$, then every element in $G$ has a finite order.

---

Define $$\mathcal H := \bigcap _{H \ne \left\{e \right\}}H$$
Since $\mathcal H$ is the  intersection of a nonempty family of subgroups of $G$  hence $\mathcal H \le G$,from the definition of intesction it follows that there is another $h \ne e$ such that $h \in \mathcal H$,the cyclic group $\langle h \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal H$ and from $\langle h \rangle \subseteq \mathcal H \subseteq G$ and the definition of $\mathcal H$ we conclude that  $\mathcal H$ is a subset of $\langle h \rangle$ ,Implies $\mathcal H=\langle h \rangle$.

Clearly $2 \le\text{ord}(\mathcal H )$,if the order is $2$ then $h^2=e$,otherwise we can construct a cyclic subgroup $\langle h^2 \rangle \subseteq \mathcal H$ from the previous arguments $\mathcal H= \langle h^2 \rangle$,on the other hand $h \in \langle h \rangle = \langle h^2 \rangle$ so there is some integer $k$ for which $h=h^{2k}$ if and only if $h^{2k-1}=e$.
So it's shown that $\mathcal H$ is a **finite** cyclic subgroup of $G$.

If $g \ne e$ then the subgroup generated by $g$ is a nontrivial subgroup and by the definition of $\mathcal H$: $h \in \langle h \rangle= \mathcal H \subseteq\langle g \rangle$,So there exists an integer $j$ such that $g^j=h$.

If we denote by $m$ the order of $\mathcal H$,then $(g^j)^m=h^m=e$

So every non-identity element in $G$ has a finite order (and $g=e$ has order $1$) ..

---

But there is a problems,we know that $k$ was an integer and $h^{2k-1}=e$ ,this is true to claim $\text{ord}(h)=2k-1$ as long as $2k-1$ is a **positive** integer,How do we ensure that?

And we know that $\text{ord}(g)=jm$, ,this is true as long as $jm$ is a **positive** integer,But as it's clear $j$ can be a negative inetegr and hence $jm$ would be a negative integer and hence cannot be the order of an element (since the order of an element is always a positive integer).

So how can someone explain that?

Comment: So the intersection of all non-trivial subgroups of $G$ is non-trivial, is that the right starting point? The phrasing seems difficult to understand, because you have written "the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups of $G$ with its trivial subgroup denoted by $\{e\}$", so it feels like you are intersecting every nontrivial subgroup with the trivial subgroup, which I am sure is not what you want to say. In your intersection, you want all the non-trivial subgroups of $G$, and that result is non-trivial.

Comment: No problem, I have seen your attempt, and it is nice! +1

Comment: If $g$ has infinite order then intersection of subgroups($\ne \{e\}$) of $<g>$ is $\{e\}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems aren't really problems. In general, if $x^n=e$ then $x^{-n}=e^{-1}=e$.

But please note that showing $x^n=e$ doesn't necessarily mean $ord(x)=n$, even when $n$ is positive. It just means that $ord(x)$ divides $n$.

In conclusion, if you know $x^n=e$, and $n\neq 0$,  then you can conclude that $ord(x)$ is finite and divides $|n|$.

So in your proof you know that $ord(h)$ divides $|2k-1|$, and later you know that $ord(g)$ divides $|jm|$. But this is good enough for what you want.

---

*Final remark on writing.* The way you have written the problem is still confusing/incorrect. For example, in the title you write
$$
\forall \{e\}\neq H\leq G : \bigcap_{H\neq\{e\}}H\neq \{e\}
$$
If I rephrase this in words it says: "For every nontrivial subgroup of $G$, the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups of $G$ is nontrivial." So the point is that you don't need to say "$\forall \{e\}\neq H\leq G$". The assertion "$\bigcap_{H\neq \{e\}}H\neq\{e\}$" is a complete phrase on it's own (as long as it's understood from context that the letter $H$ refers to subgroups, otherwise you might write $\bigcap_{\{e\}\neq H\leq G}H$ instead).

For a comparison, this would be similar to writing "for all $n\geq 1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$" instead of just "$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$". The first statement is confusing, while the second statement is complete and correctly written.

Comment: If $j=0$ then $h=g^j=e$, which contradicts the fact that $h$ generates the nontrivial group $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: If you want to, then you can formally say $\infty$ divides $0$ if you formally define $\infty\cdot 0=0$ (but remember that in calculus $\infty\cdot 0$ is an indeterminate form). But this is all getting very off track from your problem because the numbers you care about ($2k-1$ and $jm$) are **not** $0$.

Comment: In a group $G$, the order of an element $x$ is *defined* to be the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $x^m=e$ (and if no such integer exists then the order is infinite). So if you show that $x^n=e$ for some **nonzero** $n$ (which you have done in both cases) then you know that $x$ has finite order by definition, and you can further prove that the order of $x$ divides $n$.